# How to create a hierarchical column structure in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to make one column the 'parent' column to a different column in a SAS data set.

Here is the data set:

```
Column1    Column2
Class1     Subclass1
Class1     Subclass2
Class1     Subclass3
Class2     Subclass4
Class2     Subclass5
Class3     Subclass6
```

I would like to create the following column, where the subclasses are listed below each class (with indentations):

```
NewColumn
Class1
   Subclass1
   Subclass2
   Subclass3
Class2
   Subclass4
   Subclass5
   Subclass6
```

Question: How can I do this in SAS?

Comment: Usually that would be for a report, not a data set. Are you doing something like a table of characteristics or summary results from regressions? You can often use PROC REPORT for that.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I'm looking to generate this with PROC REPORT>

Comment: I don't have time to mock up a solution, but the 'modern' way to do this uses INDENT or LEFTMARGIN and sets it conditionally. This is quick example of how that would work: https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ods-pdf-proc-report-indent-column-conditionally/td-p/85624

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That form of categorical hierarchical display is often desired in output from procs `TABULATE` or `REPORT` when also statistically measuring an associated response variable.

Here is some sample code for those procs:

```
title;
ods html close;
ods html style=plateau;

data have;
  do rows = 1 to 100;
    _n_ = ceil(3*ranuni(123));
    level1 = cats('Class', _n_);
    level2 = cats('Subclass ', ceil(3*(_n_-1) + 3 * ranuni(123)));
    x = _n_ * 100 + ceil (50*ranuni(123));
    output;
  end;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class level1 level2;
  var x;
  table  
    level1 * (all level2)
    ,
    x * (mean n)
    /
    nocellmerge
  ;
run;    

proc report data=have;
  columns level1 level2 nested x x=n;
  define level1 / group noprint;
  define level2 / group noprint;
  define nested / computed  width=50;
  define x / 'X (Mean)' mean format=6.2;
  define n / 'N' N;
  break before level1 / summarize;
  compute nested / char length=50;
    if missing(level2) then 
      nested = level1;
    else
      nested = "A0202020"x || level2;
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: `REPORT` code was fixed to have better header cells, but the image was not updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can kind of replicate this output using proc means, but if you actually want this in a dataset you can use the following:

```
data want;
set have;
by column1 column2;
format new_column $15.;
if first.column1 then do;
    new_column=column1;
    output;
end;
new_column=put(column2,$15. -r); * right align;
output;
run;
```